# How to send jquery array to php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have problem in send jquery array to php? First, I have 1 form in html and I click add and I have 2 form now.Next, Im input data in form to the jquery array and after from jquery array I can't post to php array variable. How solution to this problem? Please help me master, Thanks

```
<?php

        $pertama = json_decode($_POST['pertama']); //can not work
        $kedua = json_decode($_POST['kedua']);
        foreach($pertama as $k=>$val)
        {
            $date = $val;
            $work =$kedua[$k];
        }

        echo $pertama;

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> test </title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <div class="inputs">
                <div>
                <a href="#" id="add">Add</a> | <a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>
                <input type="text" name="nama[]" class="pertama"/></div>
                <input type="text" name="lahir[]" class="kedua"/></div>
                </div>
                <input name="submit" type="button" class="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_wrapper">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var i = $('input').size();

            $('#add').click(function() {
                $('<div><input type="text" class="pertama" name="nama[]" required/><input type="text" class="kedua" name="lahir[]" /></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
                i++;
            });

            $('#remove').click(function() {
                if(i > 0) {
                    $('.pertama:last,.kedua:last').remove();
                    i--;
                }
            });

            $('#reset').click(function() {
                while(i > 2) {
                    $('.pertama:last,.kedua:last').remove();
                    i--;
                }
            });

            // here's our click function for when the forms submitted

            $('.submit').click(function(){

                var arraysatu = [];
                var arraydua = [];
                $.each($('.pertama'), function() {
                    arraysatu.push($(this).val());
                });

                $.each($('.kedua'), function() {
                    arraydua.push($(this).val());
                });

                $.post('test2.php', { arraysatu: JSON.stringify(arraysatu), arraydua: JSON.stringify(arraydua), function(data) { 
                    alert(data);
                });

            });

        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code has a syntax error. Is `{ arraysatu: JSON.stringify(arraysatu)` a typo?

Comment: Forgot to close a bracket.

Comment: Please try to add some troubleshooting information , not just the code. Errors thrown either at server or in browser console would be helpful. Also steps you have taken to debug this

Comment: would not these be better like: `$('.pertama').each(function() {
      arraysatu.push($(this).val());
    });`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close a bracket in your `post` method, I am assuming the last function is your callback and everything before that is your data.

```html
<?php

        $pertama = json_decode($_POST['pertama']); //can not work
        $kedua = json_decode($_POST['kedua']);
        foreach($pertama as $k=>$val)
        {
            $date = $val;
            $work =$kedua[$k];
        }

        echo $pertama;

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> test </title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <form>
                <div class="inputs">
                <div>
                <a href="#" id="add">Add</a> | <a href="#" id="remove">Remove</a>
                <input type="text" name="nama[]" class="pertama"/></div>
                <input type="text" name="lahir[]" class="kedua"/></div>
                </div>
                <input name="submit" type="button" class="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field_wrapper">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            var i = $('input').size();

            $('#add').click(function() {
                $('<div><input type="text" class="pertama" name="nama[]" required/><input type="text" class="kedua" name="lahir[]" /></div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.inputs');
                i++;
            });

            $('#remove').click(function() {
                if(i > 0) {
                    $('.pertama:last,.kedua:last').remove();
                    i--;
                }
            });

            $('#reset').click(function() {
                while(i > 2) {
                    $('.pertama:last,.kedua:last').remove();
                    i--;
                }
            });

            // here's our click function for when the forms submitted

            $('.submit').click(function(){

                var arraysatu = [];
                var arraydua = [];
                $.each($('.pertama'), function() {
                    arraysatu.push($(this).val());
                });

                $.each($('.kedua'), function() {
                    arraydua.push($(this).val());
                });

                $.post('test2.php', { arraysatu: JSON.stringify(arraysatu), arraydua: JSON.stringify(arraydua)}, function(data) { 
                    alert(data);
                });

            });

        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close Brackets :

```
{ arraysatu: JSON.stringify(arraysatu), arraydua: JSON.stringify(arraydua) } <====
```

Answer (score -2):

Spot the differences:

```
$pertama = json_decode($_POST['pertama']); //can not work
                               ^^^^^^^
$kedua = json_decode($_POST['kedua']);
                             ^^^^^
$.post('test2.php', { arraysatu: JSON.stringify(arraysatu), arraydua: JSON.stringify(arraydua), function(data) {
                       ^^^^^^^^                             ^^^^^^^^
```

Note the name differences.

Answer (score -2):

In the examples section of [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), you can see how to send an array to the server. Have you tried with:

```
$.post('test2.php', 
       {"arraysatu[]": arraysatu, 
        "arraydua[]": arraydua}, 
        function(data) { 
                alert(data);
            });
```

Comment: still not working, can you help me? Thanks

Comment: This is working for me: $.post("test2.php", {"arraysatu": arraysatu, "arraydua":arraydua}, function(){alert("fin");});